# How Can we store the frequency of alphabets in a string?

Tags: algorithm

How can we store the frequency of alphabets in a string using minimum possible memory..

I think bit array or using bit manipulation, this cannot be achieved as we need to store the frequency, and not only the occurrence of alphabet(true or false)...

Please let me know, if any other data structure exist for this problem..

also, we need to find the alphabets which has maximum frequency (aplhabets with same maximum frequency ) should get printed.?? Please i need an efficient alogrithm...

Comment: Do you mean the frequencies of _letters_? So "abad" has frequencies 2,1,0,1,0,0,0... ?

Comment: Do you also need time efficient solution, or minimal memory will suffice?

Comment: I need solutions. which could be the best.... People you can give any no. of algorithms available for this. I would like to know all algorithms, with which this question can be done..... This is a very important question for me.... Guys.. Please post some solutions....

Answer (score 3):

I think [Huffman coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) is what you want, but explain your problem more to understand it better, there are some other ways, but you should explain your problem (At least I'm one of a person needs more explanation).

Comment: It is a simple problem.. There is a string.. and from that string, we need to store the frequency of characters that exist in that string....

Comment: @AGeek, like what MSalters said in comments?

Comment: @AGeek, In normal way you can keep a list of length 26 of int, memory usage is 4 * 26 byte and I think it's not very big, if is big, please explain your problem situation, may be another way (not saving slphabet count) is better.

Comment: No.... This is the simple interview question.... i was finding the solution to this problem only... but using minimum memory, smthing at bit-level... but i think this is not applicable at bit level, because we want the frequency of character occurrences.......

Comment: @Saeed i don't think huffman code would do.In Huffman code we already know the frequency of occurence of each character but it is not the case here.Guys please think it over.

Comment: @Algorithmist, yes, I wrote this when I doesn't know good about question, see comments for more detail.

Comment: @AGeek, I think it's not important improve this until needed, you can say to interviewer your idea is ... if interviewer wants more optimum, you should say in which system, it should be in embedded systems, because lower memory  allocation is important, and you can think are you like work on this company or not (may be there is another system but you should find it's useful for you or not) each question which asked in interview isn't real question, sometimes interviewer wants to know you can work on problems or not.

Answer (score 1):

/* For a short string, like "abaz" a Hashmap like (a:2, b:1, z:1) will be shorter, than a whole alphabet*/

```
main()

{

  int count,i,j;
  char str[50];

  printf("Enter string : ");
  gets(str);

  for(i=0;i<=strlen(str)-1;i++)
  {
          count=1;
          if(str[i]==' ')
             continue;
          for(j=i+1;j<=strlen(str)-1;j++)
          {   
                 if(str[i]==str[j])
                 {
                        str[j]=' ';
                        count++;
                 }
          }
          printf("%c : %d \n",str[i],count);
  }                
  getch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a short string, like "abaz" a Hashmap like (a:2, b:1, z:1) will be shorter, than a whole alphabet.

Is it just for ascii a-z, or are UTF-8 characters considered?

Comment: and how long is a typical text?

Answer (score 0):

Create a HashMap having the characters mapped to the frequency. Also keep a maximum count and increment it when needed. At the end, you have all the frequencies stored and the maximum count. Now iterate over the hashmap and pick the character keys which are mapped to a value equal to maximum count.

Storing = O(n)
Retrieving all the characters with maximum frequency = O(n)

So, both together are done in linear time.